# Emacs auto-completion mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

New with emacs. I'm not able to implement auto-completion for  Gtk+3. I'm using CEDET and  Auto Complete Mode as UI.  Semantic is unable to find include files (  ), but it can parse the tags of the code in the open buffers.

Here my .emacs conf

```
;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet-1.0/common/cedet.el")
(global-ede-mode 1)
(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
;;(semantic-load-enable-semantic-debugging-helpers)
;; ede customization
(require 'semantic-lex-spp)
(ede-enable-generic-projects)
(setq senator-minor-mode-name "SN")
(setq semantic-imenu-auto-rebuild-directory-indexes nil)
(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)
(global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode 1)
(require 'semantic-decorate-include)
;; gcc setup
(require 'semantic-gcc)
;; smart completions
(require 'semantic-ia)
(setq-mode-local c-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
             '(project unloaded system recursive))
(setq-mode-local c++-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
             '(project unloaded system recursive))
(setq-mode-local erlang-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
             '(project unloaded system recursive))
(require 'eassist)
(require 'semanticdb)
(global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)
;; gnu global support
(require 'semanticdb-global)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode)
;; ctags
(require 'semanticdb-ectag)
;;(semantic-load-enable-primary-exuberent-ctags-support)
(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode)

(defun my-cedet-hook ()
(local-set-key [(control return)] 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol)
(local-set-key "\C-c?" 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu)
(local-set-key "\C-c>" 'semantic-complete-analyze-inline)
(local-set-key "\C-cp" 'semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-cedet-hook)

;;semantic gtk gdk
(defun my-semantic-hook ()
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/" 'c-mode)
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/" 'c-mode))
(add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'my-semantic-hook)

;; END CEDET
;;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup looks OK to me; I wonder if the extra "gtk/" and "gdk/" in your add-system-includes might be the problem.  I just got this working with gtk-3.0 using:

```
(semantic-add-system-include "/usr/include/gtk-3.0" 'c-mode)
```

Then in your source file,

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

Followed by:

```
gtk_[C-c ?]
```

spends a minute or so processing all the header files, but it does return the completion menu as expected.

If this doesn't work for you, I notice you might be using an older version of CEDET.  I use the latest dev version from the bazaar repository; I highly recommend you do the same.

Comment: Thanks. After I updated CEDET and eliminated the extra "gtk gdk", semantic is working and reading the included files. It will be nice to have the http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ AutoComplete UI instead of the default. Any hint :). Thanks Again